# SQL split hexastring in different bytes

Tags: mysql, string, split, hex, google-bigquery

I've got a google bigquery looking like this:

```
    #standardSQL
SELECT
  timestamp,
  CAN_Frame, 
    TRIM(SPLIT(CAN_Frame)[OFFSET(4)]) AS bytes
FROM
  `data.source`  
WHERE
  LENGTH(CAN_Frame) > 1 and
  SUBSTR(TRIM(SPLIT(CAN_Frame)[OFFSET(4)]),1,2) IN ('83', '84')
 ORDER BY
  timestamp DESC
LIMIT
  8000
```

or like this

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
*  
FROM (
 SELECT
     timestamp,
    CAN_Frame,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(CAN_Frame, r', ([^,]+)$') AS bytes_string,
    FROM_HEX(REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(CAN_Frame, r', ([^,]+)$'), ' ', '')) AS 
bytes

  FROM `data.source`
)
WHERE SUBSTR(bytes, 1, 1) IN (b'\x83', b'\x84')

ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 8000
```

with the resulting tables:

Row timestamp        CAN_Frame        bytes
1   2017-09-29 14:31:02 UTC S,48778,410,8, 84 10 00 25 00 21 00 4F     84 10 00 
25 00 21 00 4F
2   2017-09-29 14:30:42 UTC S,35847,480,8, 83 80 00 01 00 03 00 0D     83 80 00 
01 00 03 00 0D
3   2017-09-29 14:30:40 UTC S,34612,4B2,8, 84 B2 00 27 00 08 00 03     84 B2 00 
27 00 08 00 03

or

Row     timestamp      CAN_Frame       bytes_string      bytes
1   2017-09-29 14:31:02 UTC S,48778,410,8, 84 10 00 25 00 21 00 4F  84 10 00 25 00 21 00 4F hBAAJQAhAE8=
2   2017-09-29 14:30:42 UTC S,35847,480,8, 83 80 00 01 00 03 00 0D  83 80 00 01 00 03 00 0D g4AAAQADAA0=
3   2017-09-29 14:30:40 UTC S,34612,4B2,8, 84 B2 00 27 00 08 00 03  84 B2 00 27 00 08 00 03 hLIAJwAIAAM=
4   2017-09-29 14:30:39 UTC S,34314,4C0,8, 84 C0 00 1C 00 15 00 07  84 C0 00 1C 00 15 00 07 hMAAHAAVAAc=

My problem and question is now how to split the 8 byte hexa string in a way that let me have the 6th and 7th byte of string beginning with 83, the 8th byte from 83 and the 3rd byte from 84 and the 4th and 5th byte of the string beginning with 84. these datapairs are values with lsb msb in unsigned int that i need to read.

i hope somebody can help me or at least understand my problem.

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `data.source` AS (
  SELECT 'S,0,2B3,8, C2 B3 00 00 00 00 03 DE' AS frame UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,3FA,6, 00 E0 04 A5 00 0B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,440,8, 83 40 4E A5 00 47 00 64' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,450,8, 84 50 01 12 01 19 01 B3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,4B0,8, 84 B0 4E A5 00 43 00 64' 
)
SELECT
  frame, bytes, STRING_AGG(b, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS selected_bytes
FROM (
  SELECT frame, TRIM(SPLIT(frame)[OFFSET(4)]) AS bytes, SUBSTR(TRIM(SPLIT(frame)[OFFSET(4)]), 1, 2) AS f
  FROM `data.source`
  WHERE SUBSTR(TRIM(SPLIT(frame)[OFFSET(4)]), 1, 2) IN ('83', '84')
), UNNEST(SPLIT(bytes, ' ')) AS b WITH OFFSET AS p
WHERE CASE f WHEN '83' THEN p IN (5, 6, 7) WHEN '84' THEN p IN (2, 3, 4) END
GROUP BY frame, bytes
-- ORDER BY frame
```

result is:

```sql
frame                               bytes                       selected_bytes
S,0,440,8, 83 40 4E A5 00 47 00 64  83 40 4E A5 00 47 00 64     47 00 64
S,0,450,8, 84 50 01 12 01 19 01 B3  84 50 01 12 01 19 01 B3     01 12 01
S,0,4B0,8, 84 B0 4E A5 00 43 00 64  84 B0 4E A5 00 43 00 64     4E A5 00
```

Update for:

> byte 6 and 7 from the string beginning with 83 called Aiout
>   one column contains byte 8 from the string beginning with 83 and byte 3 from the string beginning with 84 called Biout
>   one column contains byte 4 and 5 from the string beginning with 84 called Avout
>   Bvout containing byte 6 and 7 from the string beginning with 84

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `data.source` AS (
  SELECT 'S,0,2B3,8, C2 B3 00 00 00 00 03 DE' AS frame UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,3FA,6, 00 E0 04 A5 00 0B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,440,8, 83 40 4E A5 00 47 00 64' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,450,8, 84 50 01 12 01 19 01 B3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,4B0,8, 84 B0 4E A5 00 43 00 64' 
)
SELECT
  frame, bytes, 
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN f='83' AND p IN (5, 6) THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Aiout,
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN (f='83' AND p=7) OR (f='84' AND p=2)  THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Biout,
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN f='84' AND p IN (3, 4) THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Avout,
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN f='84' AND p IN (5, 6) THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Bvout
FROM (
  SELECT frame, TRIM(SPLIT(frame)[OFFSET(4)]) AS bytes, SUBSTR(TRIM(SPLIT(frame)[OFFSET(4)]), 1, 2) AS f
  FROM `data.source`
  WHERE SUBSTR(TRIM(SPLIT(frame)[OFFSET(4)]), 1, 2) IN ('83', '84')
), UNNEST(SPLIT(bytes, ' ')) AS b WITH OFFSET AS p
GROUP BY frame, bytes
ORDER BY frame
```

with output as

```sql
frame                               bytes                   Aiout   Biout   Avout   Bvout
S,0,440,8, 83 40 4E A5 00 47 00 64  83 40 4E A5 00 47 00 64 47 00   64
S,0,450,8, 84 50 01 12 01 19 01 B3  84 50 01 12 01 19 01 B3         01      12 01   19 01
S,0,4B0,8, 84 B0 4E A5 00 43 00 64  84 B0 4E A5 00 43 00 64         4E      A5 00   43 00
```

Comment: thanks for this approach. ultimately i need 4 columns extracted from the bytes. one column contains byte 6 and 7 from the string beginning with 83 called Aiout; one column contains byte 8 from the string beginning with 83 and byte 3 from the string beginning with 84 called Biout; one column contains byte 4 and 5 from the string beginning with 84 called Avout and the last column is Bvout containing byte 6 and 7 from the string beginning with 84.

Comment: i thought you might want to do some little extra by yourself? example shown in the answer is good enough for this, isn't it?