# bigquery hex string to bytes/int

Tags: sql, string, int, hex, google-bigquery

is there a possibility to convert a hex string consisting of two bytes to bytes/int whereas the first byte is the lsb and the second is the msb.

after processing this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  timestamp, CAN_Frame, bytes,
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN f='83' AND p IN (5, 6) THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Aiout,
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN (f='83' AND p=7) OR (f='84' AND p=2)  THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Biout, 
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN f='84' AND p IN (3, 4) THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Avout,
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN f='84' AND p IN (5, 6) THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Bvout
FROM (
  SELECT timestamp, CAN_Frame, TRIM(SPLIT(CAN_Frame)[OFFSET(4)]) AS bytes, 
SUBSTR(TRIM(SPLIT(CAN_Frame)[OFFSET(4)]), 1, 2) AS f 
  FROM `data.source`
  WHERE SUBSTR(TRIM(SPLIT(CAN_Frame)[OFFSET(4)]), 1, 2) IN ('83', '84')
), UNNEST(SPLIT(bytes, ' ')) AS b WITH OFFSET AS p
GROUP BY timestamp,CAN_Frame, bytes 
ORDER BY timestamp desc
```

(thanks to Mikhail Berlyant)

i've got 4 columns (aiout,biout,avout,bvout) with each consisting of two bytes in a hex string looking like this:

```
       Aiout    Biout  Avout    Bvout
                 00    25 00    21 00 
       03 00      0D                   
                  00   27 00    08 00 
                 00    1C 00    15 00 
                 00    25 00    21 00 
       03 00      03                   
                  00   2A 00    26 00 
       03 00      0D                   
       00 00      07                   
       04 00      04
```

with functions like cast, format, integer, ... i've got always an internal error and the request could not be completed.

best regards

Comment: If you are getting an internal error, please file a bug report with a job ID on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B) so that someone can look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that builds on [Mikhail's answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46648403/6253347). It takes the space-separated bytes and turns them into a string prepended with `0x` with no spaces that can be cast to an int64:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION HexToInt(hex_string STRING) AS (
  IFNULL(SAFE_CAST(CONCAT('0x', REPLACE(hex_string, ' ', '')) AS INT64), 0)
);

WITH `data.source` AS (
  SELECT 'S,0,2B3,8, C2 B3 00 00 00 00 03 DE' AS frame UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,3FA,6, 00 E0 04 A5 00 0B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,440,8, 83 40 4E A5 00 47 00 64' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,450,8, 84 50 01 12 01 19 01 B3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,4B0,8, 84 B0 4E A5 00 43 00 64' 
)
SELECT *,
  HexToInt(Aiout) AS Aiout_int64,
  HexToInt(Biout) AS Biout_int64,
  HexToInt(Avout) AS Avout_int64,
  HexToInt(Bvout) AS Bvout_int64
FROM (
  SELECT
    frame, bytes,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN f='83' AND p IN (5, 6) THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Aiout,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN (f='83' AND p=7) OR (f='84' AND p=2)  THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Biout,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN f='84' AND p IN (3, 4) THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Avout,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN f='84' AND p IN (5, 6) THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Bvout
  FROM (
    SELECT frame, TRIM(SPLIT(frame)[OFFSET(4)]) AS bytes, SUBSTR(TRIM(SPLIT(frame)[OFFSET(4)]), 1, 2) AS f
    FROM `data.source`
    WHERE SUBSTR(TRIM(SPLIT(frame)[OFFSET(4)]), 1, 2) IN ('83', '84')
  ), UNNEST(SPLIT(bytes, ' ')) AS b WITH OFFSET AS p
  GROUP BY frame, bytes
  ORDER BY frame
);
```

The output looks like this:

```
+------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|               frame                |          bytes          |    Aiout    |   Biout   |    Avout    |    Bvout    | Aiout_int64 | Biout_int64 | Avout_int64 | Bvout_int64 |
+------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| S,0,440,8, 83 40 4E A5 00 47 00 64 | 83 40 4E A5 00 47 00 64 |      47 00  |        64 |             |             |       18176 |         100 |           0 |           0 |
| S,0,450,8, 84 50 01 12 01 19 01 B3 | 84 50 01 12 01 19 01 B3 |             |   01      |    12 01    |      19 01  |           0 |           1 |        4609 |        6401 |
| S,0,4B0,8, 84 B0 4E A5 00 43 00 64 | 84 B0 4E A5 00 43 00 64 |             |   4E      |    A5 00    |      43 00  |           0 |          78 |       42240 |       17152 |
+------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Edit: if you want to change the order in which the bytes are interpreted, you can reverse the contents before casting, e.g.:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION HexReverse(hex_string STRING) AS (
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(s, ' ' ORDER BY off DESC)
   FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(hex_string, ' ')) AS s WITH OFFSET off)
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION HexToInt(hex_string STRING) AS (
  IFNULL(SAFE_CAST(CONCAT('0x', REPLACE(HexReverse(hex_string), ' ', '')) AS INT64), 0)
);

WITH `data.source` AS (
  SELECT 'S,0,2B3,8, C2 B3 00 00 00 00 03 DE' AS frame UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,3FA,6, 00 E0 04 A5 00 0B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,440,8, 83 40 4E A5 00 47 00 64' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,450,8, 84 50 01 12 01 19 01 B3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S,0,4B0,8, 84 B0 4E A5 00 43 00 64' 
)
SELECT *,
  HexToInt(Aiout) AS Aiout_int64,
  HexToInt(Biout) AS Biout_int64,
  HexToInt(Avout) AS Avout_int64,
  HexToInt(Bvout) AS Bvout_int64
FROM (
  SELECT
    frame, bytes,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN f='83' AND p IN (5, 6) THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Aiout,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN (f='83' AND p=7) OR (f='84' AND p=2)  THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Biout,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN f='84' AND p IN (3, 4) THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Avout,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN f='84' AND p IN (5, 6) THEN b ELSE '' END, ' ' ORDER BY p) AS Bvout
  FROM (
    SELECT frame, TRIM(SPLIT(frame)[OFFSET(4)]) AS bytes, SUBSTR(TRIM(SPLIT(frame)[OFFSET(4)]), 1, 2) AS f
    FROM `data.source`
    WHERE SUBSTR(TRIM(SPLIT(frame)[OFFSET(4)]), 1, 2) IN ('83', '84')
  ), UNNEST(SPLIT(bytes, ' ')) AS b WITH OFFSET AS p
  GROUP BY frame, bytes
  ORDER BY frame
);
```

Comment: thanks for this solution! so it's solved with a tempory function. the problem is that the bytes are in little endian. it's a problem i solved with the used presentation program (tableau) but it would be nice to know a way in bigquery programming

Comment: I added another example showing how you can reverse the bytes in `HexToInt` before casting to an int64.